# With NodeJS/npm how can I run Linux command in Windows and others?

Tags: linux, node.js, find, gruntjs, npm

I created a [nodejs](http://nodejs.org) tool with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) that uses [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command in Linux. When I run the module in Windows, the [`find`](http://www.computerhope.com/findhlp.htm) command is different, so I won't get the same result.

This is the grunt task:

```
    exec: {
        collectJSON: {
            cmd: "find " + PROJECT_PATH + " -path '**/" + DIST_REGION + "/**/*.json' ! -name '_*'",
            stdout: false,
            callback: function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                grunt.file.write(jsonPath, stdout);
            }
        }
    },
```

I heard that npm is a package manager and it can take any "program" as our module's dependency, so I was wonder if there is any npm package can help me to run the `find` command in Windows (and others environment as well).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No. Write the find operation in is JS, or find existing JS module. Anything else is way too fragile and complex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nodejs process.stdin.resume() doesn't work in Cygwin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218542/nodejs-process-stdin-resume-doesnt-work-in-cygwin)